# High voltage DC power supplier

Tags: voltage, high-voltage, interference

I am working on physics research, and I am using the DC High voltage supplier ~30KV from the wall AC power.

I am not sure what is happening, but when I apply more than 3kV it start to interfere with other device such as computer monitor is blanking. Not just monitor, I think it make all other electronic device to be blinking, such as some of our feedback control and power supplier.

I don't really have good knowledge about the electronics. What can be possible issue? I am afraid too much voltage is going to ground and that ground is affecting other device's ground? or does it create the magnetic field, so do I need some shield around it?

---

For more detail, I am applying the power to the Rubidum85 atom contained cell, and apply at the two small plate distanced 2.5mm Which will create the electric field in order to see the energy level shift on atom.
[image]

---

Comment: What are you doing with the 30KV?

Comment: @JRE I updated!

Comment: Is that 30KV DC or AC or pulsed in some way?

Comment: How far apart are the plates?  Are they in air or in vacuum or some other gas?

Comment: @JRE I editted, it is DC and also it is rubidum 85 with 2mm distance

Comment: Air breaksdown when the voltage is too high and becomes conductive.  At normal pressure, that is about 3kV per millimeter.  So, you can expect air to conduct at around 7.5kV for your 2.5mm gap.  Depending on other things, it may conduct earlier.  When it conducts, it will cause a spark which also broadcasts a lot of (broadband) RF energy.  This can cause disturbances of nearby devices.  The more current your HV power supply is capable of, the larger the disturbances.

Comment: @JRE Yes, I saw it was making a spark inside of the cell. so do we have any way to block the RF signal?

Comment: Put the cell in a metal box, and ground the box.  You may have to put the power supply in the box along with the cell.

Comment: I expect the sparking to totally disrupt whatever measurements you are trying to make.

Comment: @JRE I tried, but I saw again the interrupting other device, and suddenly one of other device's fuse got burnt. I will now try the JDavila's method, and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: Think about that resistor for minute.  It will have to be able to withstand up to 30kV, and it may have to withstand  a lot of power.  It will probably reduce the interference, but you will still have sparks.  Those will still mess up your measurements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the possibly that such a high voltage is creating a signal strong enough that disrupts other instruments or electronics.

I doubt the ground is affecting the other instruments, as that should be neutral. Try adding higher resistors along the 1K range to manage the power supply. At such a high voltage, there is more of possibility of interference occurring, because not enough of the signal is being filtered.

Here is a link explaining Electromagnetic Interference occurring from high voltage:

http://home.zcu.cz/~tesarova/IP/Proceedings/Proc_2010/Files/025%20IP2010%20Kysela.pdf

In more detail you could be dealing with Corona,

"Corona discharges are a source of radio noise. Spectral components ranging from a few kHz to 10
MHz. In this frequency band, the disturbance spreads leadership. Leadership is an effective radiator,
since the wavelength is due to the large size wires."

From the posted link. A discharge may be creating signal nose.